# How to find the percentage of null value in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

How to find the percentage of null value in a pandas dataframe?

```
Null_Values=np.sum(data.isnull())
Null_Values/len(Null_Values)
```

Answer (score 1):

*data.isnull().sum()* gives the number of *NaN* values in each column **separately**.

To compute the share of *NaN*s in the **whole** DataFrame, run:

```
data.isnull().sum().sum()/len(data)
```

Alternative solution:

```
np.count_nonzero(data.isna()) / data.size
```

Comment: how to write a for loop to find the percentage of null value that is above 60% and drops the column automatically in a pandas dataframe

Comment: It is a bad habit to post one question and then "extend" it, adding another questions. Ask **another** question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
NullValues=data.isnull().sum()/len(data)
```

Comment: how to write a for loop to find the percentage of null value  that is above 60% and drops the column automatically  in a pandas dataframe